# How the deployment strategy works for Multiple Instances of Same Microservice

Tags: deployment, microservices, service-discovery

Lets say I have 5 Microservices and each microservice has 3 instances each. To deploy these microservices Do we need 15 different servers to deploy each Microservice ???

So In large scale application Let's say i have 100 Microservice and each microservice has 3 instance running in that case i need 300 servers to deploy each microservice's instances??

Please correct me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like that 1 MicroService Instance = 1 Physical Server.

- Microservice means that service only knows about its presense and its own data.
- If some other service want to give some task to another service they have to call that service via endpoint for example Http or via bus.
- By saying this you can have a one big server and that can have all the services.
- If you want all the services belong to one instance or for one customer can be in one server, it is also possible.

In this area, you have to compute how much resource required by each service and its instance and that will be the driving factor in deciding this strategy.